# Replace text with selected item in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got dropdown in my HTML:

```
<div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" ng-model="yearName">Sort by year
          <span class="caret"></span></button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li ng-repeat="year in ctrl.getYear() | orderBy: videoYear">
              <input type="checkbox" ng-model="ctrl.filter[year]" id='year{{$index}}' class='chk-btn styled-checkbox' />
              <label for='year{{$index}}'>{{year}}</label>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

The title is 'Sort by year', now but I wanna when changed an item, its getting by title. So, if I select 1984, title should be 1984. How can I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: If it's about the button's text, then just replace the text with variable and change the variable.

Comment: @Sergey thank you but I think this is not an answer. I need a solution, example or method.

Comment: what should happen when you select two or more checkbox ?

Comment: I'll change allow one item in checkbox list later. So this is not problem. Thanks.

Comment: did my answer met your requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the code

```js
 angular.module("sampleApp", [])
   .controller('sampleCtrl', function($scope) {
     var ctrl = this;
     ctrl.filter = {};
     ctrl.getYear = function() {
       return [2001, 2002, 2003]
     }
   })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="sampleApp" ng-controller="sampleCtrl as ctrl">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" ng-model="yearName">Sort by year
      <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li ng-repeat="year in ctrl.getYear() | orderBy: videoYear">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="ctrl.filter[year]" id='year{{year}}' ng-true-value="{{year}}" class='chk-btn styled-checkbox' />

        <label for='year{{year}}'>{{year}}</label>

      </li>
    </ul>
    {{ctrl.filter}}
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is correct but not my solution probably. Because my ng-model="ctrl.filter[year]" uses another function so i can't change it.